# Why is cheese wax red?

Tags: cheese

All the cheese wax I've seen on cheese is always red. Is there a specific reason as to why this is? Can the wax be some color other than red, like maybe magenta?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't seen a lot of waxed cheese, or you've only seen a few specific ones. I can easily find (and have frequently eaten) green, black, and yellow ones, though the yellow in some cases is more of a clear wax. Other colors are possible though the range may be somewhat limited by having the cheese wax be non-toxic (generally felt to be a good idea.)

[One supplier](http://www.cheesemaking.com/cheesemakingnecessities.html) has red, clear, yellow, purple and black (no green there.) Here's the purple.

This may also be a regional thing - if all the people that buy cheese in your area expect red wax and are more likely to buy cheese waxed that color, you'll see more of it, as suppliers will learn to choose red wax when supplying that region.
[image: Purple cheese wax]

Comment: I would put a wick on that, and burn it. -Lovely!

Comment: I used a bit of remelted reclaimed cheese wax for grafting wax this year - it was a brown wax (I think actually it was a double-dip - clear then brown), and had good flexibility (not brittle) - seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. Were I live once cheese is removed from the cheese press. It is wrapped in wire. Then dipped in bees wax. As we have or candle wax. White to a light yellow. Then hung from the wire to keep rodents from getting to it. Also to protect it for late use. Maybe people like to buy red. Red & Blue items sell better in box's & such. Old selling trick. White bags with red & or blue marking's sell better in a shop.